# SQL Server IDENTITY_INSERT is on but an INSERT query complains it is not on

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I am writing a migration using MigratorDotNet for an application, and after running several thousand of similar insertions, SQL server complains:

```
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay ON
  [migrate] INSERT INTO TimeOfDay (id) VALUES ('312491')
  [migrate] [Warning] Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TimeOfDay' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay OFF
```

Just right above, there are similar insertions that succeed:

```
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay ON
  [migrate] INSERT INTO TimeOfDay (id) VALUES ('312485')
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay OFF
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay ON
  [migrate] INSERT INTO TimeOfDay (id) VALUES ('312486')
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay OFF
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT StartAndEndTime ON
  [migrate] INSERT INTO StartAndEndTime (id, Start, Finish) VALUES ('156190', '312485', '312486')
  [migrate] SET IDENTITY_INSERT StartAndEndTime OFF
```

The other columns in the TimeOfDay table default to null, and the insertion is delibrate in setting them to null.

The queries are executed using `Migrator.Providers.TransformationProvider.ExecuteNonQuery`.
Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Is it actually failing to do the insert or just warning you of what would happen if you had the setting wrong?

Comment: @Xedni It fails the insertion. In any case I need the id as a foreign key for another insertion (into StartAndEndTime)

Comment: I don't know what `[migrate]` is but is it possible that the connection was severed and re-established at that point? IDENTITY_INSERT is a session setting and if for some reason you disconnected you will have to set it again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand [migrate] is just the prefix added by Nant to the log. That might be a possibility. I could try running the entire query, including setting IDENTITY_INSERT on and off in a single call to ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: You're currently doing the SET and the INSERT in different calls?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes. It goes like `ExecuteNonQuery("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay ON"); ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO ...");ExecuteNonQuery("SET IDENTITY_INSERT TimeOfDay OFF");`. I am perplexed as to why it would work for thousands of insertions and then one would fail. It might be like you said.

Comment: I would have never put those into separate calls in the first place. You've merely been lucky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the solution to this was to call the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` commands with the `INSERT` operation in the same call to `ExecuteNonQuery`. Previously, they were done in separate calls to `ExecuteNonQuery`, which as Aaron Bertrand said might fail because the connection might reset between the calls.